# Звідки походить слово Дзідзьо?

Tags: етимологія

Наскільки мені відомо, слово **дзідзьо** західноукраїнського діалекту означає дід, а **дедьо** -- батько.
Я намагався знайти хоч яку небудь інформацію стосовно походження цих слів, але знайшов лише декілька сайтів без жодних пояснень. Хоча вони і розповсюджені на території Прикарпаття, Карпат та Закарпаття.
Тому власне питання:

звідки походять ці слова та наскільки вони старі?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ці слова, а також «мама», «тато», «баба», «тятя» та подібні до них найменування близьких родичів походять з так званої [дитячої мови](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk), вони, як правило, двоскладові, один і той самий приголосний повторюється, часто повторюється й голосний. Явище це ґлобальне, зустрічається практично в усіх мовах, ці слова дуже давні. Скажімо, слово «мама» є фактично в кожній мові, від індіанських мов Америки (головне божество інків – Пачамама, Матір Земля), до племенних мов Африки та Азії, хоча в деяких мовах, зокрема в грузинській та в чінукському жаргоні, воно означає «тато». При цьому в грузинській «мама, матір» звучить як დედა «дéда», і теж відноситься до слів, що походять з дитячої мови.

В автентичности слова «дзідзьо» сумніватися немає причин, в навколишніх мовах, в русинській, в словацькій, угорській та польській подібного слова немає.

Comment: «В навколишніх мовах, в русинській, словацькій, угорській та польській подібного слова немає». Добродію, "русинська" це і є "українська", просто автентичніша її назва. Мої предки себе українцями до часів Сталіна й не звали, а коли їхали на окуповану східним сусідом землі, казали "їдемо на Велику Україну", а проте мова наша ідентична тому, як говорять у Києві. Не діліть Україну, її нарід, політики це добре роблять й без вас.

Comment: @Олег - Вибачте, Олеже, та я не можу погодитися, що немає такої окремої мови як русинська. У питаннях лінгвістики думка носіїв мови важить мало, важать лише факти, а факти красномовно кажуть, що відмінности русинської від української на всіх рівнях мови такі, що їх достатньо, аби вважати русинську окремою слов'янською мовою, і я не один це бачу, є достатньо й инших лінгвістів, які згодні зі мною. Авторитет ваших предків, звісно, дуже поважний, та не можна покладатися просто лише на авторитет, коли йдеться про науку, бо нам, лінгвістам, науковцям, потрібні _факти_.

Answer (score 2):

Основа *дід* є загальнослов'янською, і закінчувалось на зредукований голосний `ъ`: *дѣдъ*. В більшості слів, що закінчувались на зредукований, тепер закінчення нульове, але в деяких словах зредуковане підсилилось і вижило. Порівняйте: *Петръ* - *Петро*. Щоправда, найчастіше зредуковані вижили в середині слова (повноголосся): *вълкъ*, *зьрно* - *вовк*, *зерно*.

*Дідо* зустрічається на львівщині без дзенькання. Походження дзенькання в *дзідзьо* не знаю, але, скажімо, в білоруській *дзед*.

Comment: А може це прийшло від поліщуків. Наскільки мені відомо дзенькання найбільше притаманне білорусам, а у поліщуків з білорусами багато спільних мовних елементів.